# What's the next number?

Tags: number-sequence

In the following sequence, what is the next number and why?

> 11, 18, 26, 34, 35, 52, 67, 74, 78, 81

Hint:

> I think I ate too much pie yesterday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The next number is

> 84

The sequence lists the

> Zero-based positions of the digit 8 in the decimal expansion of $\pi$ (like pie).

Credits to

> [A037006 - OEIS](https://oeis.org/A037006) ;-)